# How to calculate a total price JS

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
function calculate_sale_article(id){
  var article_price = $("#article_price_"+id).val()
  var article_cant = $("#article_cant_"+id).val()
  var article_discount = $("#article_discount_"+id).val()

  $("#article_ammount").val(article_price * article_cant / article_discount)
}
```

> Error: "Infinity"

This error is when `article_discount` arrives with a `0`, how can I fix this?

Comment: Use an if statement.

Comment: Also make sure all values are numbers and not strings. Cast it to a number if you need to.

Comment: You should also coerce the strings to numbers. Like, `var article_price = +$("#article_price_"+id).val()`

Comment: Divide by zero, what do you expect?

Comment: `parseInt` before doing calculations.

Comment: I don't see a close-vote reason here... Looks like a genuine question, not researched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a simple check for zero (exception handling for divide by zero). Replace the below line:

```
$("#article_ammount").val(article_price * article_cant / article_discount)
```

With something like this:

```
if (article_discount != 0)
  $("#article_ammount").val(article_price * article_cant / article_discount)
else
  $("#article_ammount").val(article_price * article_cant)
```

Comment: I guess that if the `discount` is 0, the `article_amount` should be `article_price * article_cant`, and not 0

Comment: @quirimmo I am doing an exception handling here for the `article_discount`, which is the divisor... Might have issues if not handled, right?

Comment: yeah I got your point that's totally correct, just saying that when the `article_discount` is 0, the `article_amount` should be the full price instead of 0 :)

Comment: Yep, so it is always better in checking the final value rather... `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I ***never*** down-voted, but I'd assume it's because this question should be closed rather than answered and the fact that you are a 100K user and you still answered, just an assumption...

Comment: @quirimmo Gotcha... Updated the answer.

Comment: @Script47 I understood what was the mistake. I should have closely understood the question. Well, yea, I now know the reason for the downvote. `:)`

Comment: @quirimmo I understood now, what's the mistake. Thanks... I know you didn't downvote.

Comment: @PraveenKumar As said, I never down-voted so my reasoning could be completely wrong.

Comment: @Script47 Boss, my answer **was** wrong before editing. Check the first comment... `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar sorry for the question :) I am a new user of stack overflow, just used it for answering since two months, never used before for answering, so I have no idea at the moment...how did you know that I didn't downvote it? after few points you will be able to see the users who downvoted/upvoted your answers?

Comment: @quirimmo Coz you said it and you have no reason to lie to me. Just gut feeling man... `:)`

Comment: LOL thanks @PraveenKumar I thought that after some level, you will have the ability to see the users nicknames of upvotes and downvotes :joy:

Comment: @quirimmo That access is only available with the employees of stack exchange, that too stringently noted. Not even available for moderators... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    var article_price = parseInt($("#article_price_"+id).val());
      var article_cant = parseInt($("#article_cant_"+id).val());
 var discount = parseInt($("#article_discount_"+id).val());
      var article_discount = discount?discount:1;

      $("#article_ammount").val(article_price * article_cant / article_discount)
```

Comment: Could have explained.

Comment: This expression `var article_discount = discount?discount:1;` could be written as `var article_discount = discount || 1;`

Comment: @quirimmo LoL. I know... He he... I was letting the new users know the right way of answering.

Comment: @PraveenKumar yeah I know :)  the comment was referred to Sundar :)

Comment: I know. It was not a question :)